# Null Listener in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Listener in Android Studio RecyclerView custom adapter is returning null.

This is the Interface

```
  private OnItemClickListener mlistener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position, Boolean paid);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mlistener = listener;
    }
```

And this is the View Holder with the Listener. This is intended to pass a Boolean to the main activity.

```
 public CartViewHolder(View itemView, ArrayList<Shift> shifts, OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

         
            paid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.due_back_paid);
            containerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);


            paid.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (listener !=  null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position, isChecked);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            containerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Shift current = (Shift)containerView.getTag();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewShiftActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("thisShift", current);
                    intent.putExtra("shifts", shifts);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


        }


    }

    public LoadAdapter(ArrayList<Shift> shifts){
        shiftList = shifts;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shift_row, parent, false);
        CartViewHolder mvh = new CartViewHolder(view, shiftList, mlistener);
        return mvh;
    }
```

I have used this code in other projects and it works. I have can't seem to figure out what I am missing.

I've been asked to include the activity. The following is this code.
I have not added any code to the onItemClick here yet. waiting for the listener to work.

```
public class EditShiftActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoadAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

    private ArrayList<Shift> shifts;
    private RecyclerView lRecyclerView;
    private LoadAdapter lAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lLayoutManager;
    private View view;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_shift);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        shifts = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("shifts");

        fab = findViewById(R.id.add_shift_edit);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(EditShiftActivity.this, AddShiftActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("shifts", shifts);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
        
        lRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.shift_recycler);
        lLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        lAdapter = new LoadAdapter(shifts);
        lRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(lLayoutManager);
        lRecyclerView.setAdapter(lAdapter);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, Boolean paid) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Share your activity code too, where you have implemented this adapter.

Comment: Priyanka, i have added the Activity. Thanks

Comment: I do not see where you call `setOnItemClickListener( with a listener implementation )`.

Comment: It's in the first block of code. 

Comment: You missed one line, do check my answer and add this. Code will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line in your code -

```
lAdapter = new LoadAdapter(shifts);
lAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the `ArrayList<Shifts>` from Intent. Check the size of `shifts` arraylist before sending to the Adapter. There is a chance that if the arraylist passed is empty then the adapter will return `null` and hence `lRecyclerView` will not be displayed.

Add this condition before passing data to adapter

```java
//condition to check whether the arraylist is empty or not
if(!shifts.isEmpty()) {

 lAdapter = new LoadAdapter(shifts);
 
 //initialising the adapter
 lRecyclerView.setAdapter(lAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll add that to my code in the future. It wasn't the problem though. Thanks for your time 